# Unknown mappedBy in: com.debatz.mistergift.model.User.token, referenced property unknown: com.debatz.mistergift.model.Token.user

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat

I'm not able to solve this new exception when I deploy my war into Tomcat 8 (using mvn tomcat:run-war command).

Here is the pasted exception:

> GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mg-em-default' defined in class path resource [WEB-INF/data-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: mistergift_pu] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: mistergift_pu] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1225)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:119)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:853)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
>       ... 21 more
>
> **Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.debatz.mistergift.model.User.token, referenced property unknown: com.debatz.mistergift.model.Token.user**
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:160)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1695)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1424)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
>       ... 29 more

And the two entities (without the getters/setters):

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "mistergift", name = "users")
public class User {

/**
 * The user id.
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

/**
 * The user first name.
 */
@Column(name = "first_name", length = 255, nullable = false)
private String firstName;

/**
 * The user last name.
 */
@Column(name = "last_name", length = 255, nullable = false)
private String lastName;

/**
 * The user email.
 */
@Column(name = "email", length = 100, nullable = false)
private String email;

/**
 * The user password.
 */
@Column(name = "password", length = 255, nullable = false)
private String password;

/** The user role. */
@Column(name = "role", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private Role role;

/** The user token. */
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
private Token token;

/**
 *
 */
public User() {
    this.groups = new ArrayList<Group>();
}

// ...
```

And...

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "mistergift", name = "user_token")
public class Token {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Column(name = "value", length = 75, nullable = false)
private String value;

@Column(name = "expiration_date", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date expirationDate;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "token")
private User user;

/**
 *
 */
public Token() { }

// ...
```

Can you please give me some advice to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `mappedBy` on both sides of the association.

It is incorrect

```
/** The user token. */
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
private Token token; 

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "token")
private User user;
```

Firstly, you should decide which persistent will be owner of the association ( which table will have a foreign key).
For an example, if `User` will have a foreign key column `fk_token` with `Token` identifier

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "mistergift", name = "users")
public class User {

    /** The user token. */
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_token")
    private Token token;

}

@Entity
@Table(schema = "mistergift", name = "user_token")
public class Token {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "token", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

}
```

If `Token` will have a foreign key column `fk_user` with `User` identifier

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "mistergift", name = "users")
public class User {

    /** The user token. */
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private Token token;

}

@Entity
@Table(schema = "mistergift", name = "user_token")
public class Token {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user")
    private User user;

}
```

**Updated**

The exception is rised at the line [`OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(Map)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.5.Final/org/hibernate/cfg/OneToOneSecondPass.java#159) because of `otherSideProperty == null`. Hibernate try to find `Token.user` property among  persistent classes are known to him and fail. So Hibernate doesn't consider `Token` as a persistent. Reasons can be

1. `Token` doesn't have the `@Entity` annotation.
2. `Token` is not mapped in the `hibernate.cfg.xml`.
3. Incorrect scanning of packages with persistents, as @magik [reported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35281909/3405171).

Hibernate, obviously has a very unclear and, may be, incorrect error message with this issue.

Comment: Hi v.ladynev. Thanks for your quick reply. I make the changes but unfortunatly I get the same error. Any other idea about that?

Comment: @magik Which version of Hibernate do you use?

Comment: v.ladynev I'm using hibernate-entitymanager, hibernate-core via maven version 4.3.5.Final and spring-data-jpa version 1.9.2.RELEASE

Comment: a strange thing is that Intellij seems not recognizes the relation because I have no autocompletion when I begin to type the join column name... (I decided to use the User as the owner).

Answer (score 1):

So I mark this topic as resolve. I finally found how to proceed. v.ladynev was right in his answer but I have another mistake which hide the real issue. It was my component-scan annotation which were redirected to a unexistant package (I had renamed my entities package). Thank guys!

Comment: Thank you for accept an answer. I have updated it. I was going to update it yesterday with similar considerations, but decided to do it after sleeping. May be, it is good that you find an answer yourself. :)

Comment: I find the answer thanks to you dude. It was a problem of naming I think!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code as given below, its not able to find "com.debatz.mistergift.model.Token.user " , as it works case sensitive.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "User")
```

and

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "Token")
```

I would suggest using hiberanate plugin to generate these dao classes and of couuse you can customise them .But you avoid doing some typo and save time as well.